# WxRichTextCtrl python retrieving entries from file

Tags: python

I am creating a program with a tree control and each item in the tree having data which is displayed in a wxRichTextctrl. I figured out how to get the xml data from the ctrl but I don't know how to show this in the ctrl. Like when i set setvalue() it just displays the xml as it is. Loading from file is not a valid option since I have a dictionary from which I load each record(stored in xml) else I will create a temperory file and load it which is kind of creepy.
I will be grateful if you can help me out with some example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bypass `RichTextCtrl.LoadFile()`, you have to create one of the `RichTextFileHandler` based classes and use its `LoadStream()` method to write directly into the RichTextCtrl buffer.

- RichTextPlainTextHandler
- RichTextHTMLHandler
- RichTextXMLHandler

For example:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO

# initialize a string stream with XML data
stream = StringIO( myXmlString )
# create an XML handler
handler = wx.richtext.RichTextXMLHandler()
# load the stream into the control's buffer
handler.LoadStream( myRichTextCtrl.GetBuffer(), stream )
# refresh the control
myRichTextCtrl.Refresh()
```

And to get the contents of a `RichTextCtrl` in a specific format:

```
stream = StringIO()
handler = wx.richtext.RichTextHTMLHandler()
handler.SaveStream( myRichTextCtrl.GetBuffer(), stream )
print stream.getvalue()
```

---

Alternatively, you can load the stream through the buffer directly. Please note that the appropriate handler must already exist to interpret the data:

```
# add the handler (where you create the control)
myRichTextCtrl.GetBuffer().AddHandler(wx.richtext.RichTextXMLHandler())
```

```
stream = StringIO( myXmlString )
buffer = self.myRichTextCtrl.GetBuffer()
# you have to specify the type of data to load and the control
# must already have an instance of the handler to parse it
buffer.LoadStream(stream, wx.richtext.RICHTEXT_TYPE_XML)
myRichTextCtrl.Refresh()
```

Comment: There was a problem. I tried your method and no error occurs but the screen does not get updated. I added a refresh to the control and also tried layout as I found from googling. But still nothing. After trying your method, I tried to save the buffer from the blank screen and it contains only a normal xml without any data. So I guess the ctrl wasn't updated. It isn't a display updating problem. Can you help

Comment: @GeorgeCyriac I've updated my answer with an alternative solution. Let me know if it works for you. Both versions work on winXP, py 2.7, wx 2.8/2.9.